# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebaseui' in 'C:\Users\USER\auth_form_react\src'

Tags: html, css, reactjs, firebase, visual-studio-code

In reactJs after running

```
npm start
```

it yields the following error:

```
./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebaseui' in 'C:\Users...\src'
```

(using visual studio code)

this is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "auth-form-react",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "type": "module",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "firebase": "^8.2.10",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
        "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

this is my firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'

const firebaseConfig =
 {

    //firebase config info

};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const authUI = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't installed `firebaseui` within your project.

You can install it with `npm install -s firebaseui`.

See also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebaseui#installation